# More strict compile options in GoLang

Tags: go

Is there an option in golang to fail build if a function returns a value and the returned value is not used? For example, I want an error / warning when we have:

`func abc() error`

and it is called without an lvalue as:

`abc()`

**EDIT**: This is not for errors alone but for return values in general.

Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/kisielk/errcheck can check for ignored errors. I don't think it can check for ignored return values - i.e. where you don't check the returned bytes written and error from `fmt.Printf` and variants.

Comment: Could the people adding -1 kindly explain why ? There is no sense in flagging a question without a comment. I have tried to obtain an answer and have not been able to find one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not about the compiler being strict or not. The Go Language Specification allows calling functions and methods without using their return values.

You won't see any compiler options that will stop the building process on use cases which do not violate the lang spec.

What you want may be created or may already exist as an external tool, but not in the Go compiler itself.

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for something like -Wall -Werror present in gcc. I will look for some external tools if available.

Answer (score 0):

No. even if compile can check the assignment of returned error, how could we know  the variable be checked in right way?
[faq](https://golang.org/doc/faq#exceptions) [errorhandle](http://blog.golang.org/error-handling-and-go)

Comment: This is not for error alone but any generic return value. The code is with the error is only an example.

Comment: answer still no. even if compile can check the assignment of returned value, how could we know the variable be used in right way?

Comment: I want to figure out all instances where it is not assigned. Whether it is used the right way is the halting problem and I am not trying to solve it.